# Regular Expression, Get Sub Pattern

Tags: javascript

Why am I not able to grab the subpattern? The console displays `undefined` when I am expecting `hello` to be output. If I change `matches[1]` to `matches[0]` I get `{{hello}}`. So, Why can I not access the subpattern?

```
var str     = "{{hello}}";
var matches = str.match(/{{(.+)}}/ig);

console.log(matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
str.match(/{{(.+)}}/i);
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're looking for the behavior of `RegExp.exec`. MDN states this:

> If the regular expression does not include the g flag, returns the same result as regexp.exec(string). ...
>   If the regular expression includes the g flag, the method returns **an Array containing all matches.**

Since you had the `g` flag, the RegExp was trying to find all global matches (basically ignoring your groupings), returning `['{{hello}}']`.

If you remove the the `g` flag (or alternatively use `/{{(.+)}}/i.exec(str)`, you can get your groupings returned.